# Haskell: Removing element from list of lists of tuples by a tuple

Tags: list, haskell, filter, tuples

I have a structure in my code which includes one list that has many lists and then these lists have tuples, which represent coordinates. Here is my situation:

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
type ShipPoints = [Point]

removeCoordinatePairFromList :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removeCoordinatePairFromList fireCoordinate enemyShips =  (filter (notElem fireCoordinate) enemyShips)
```

This doesn't work like I want, however. This removes the whole sublist inside the parent list where matching coordinate pair is found. I want that only the one tuple that matches fireCoordinate is removed from the sublist and everything else stays same. Context is battleship game and ShipPoints type represent any kind of ship coordinates in list. [ShipPoints] means all the ship coordinates from one player.

Comment: Hint: Use `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want go through the list of `ShipPoints` and remove the `Point` from every `ShipPoints` where it appears.  This can be done with a `map`:

```
removePointFromShipList :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePointFromShipList p lst = map (removePointFromShip p) lst
```

This uses a helper function:

```
removePointFromShip :: Point -> ShipPoints -> ShipPoints
```

that removes the `Point` from a specific `ShipPoints`.  This helper function can be defined with a filter:

```
removePointFromShip p shp = filter (/= p) shp
```

---

I think the above functions are straightforward and don't really need to be improved, but since Haskell programmers can't leave well enough alone, most (including me) would try to refactor this.  Feel free to ignore this part or just skim through it for fun.

Anyway, many Haskellers would move the `removePointFromShip` function into a `where` clause and maybe shorten the names:

```
removePoint :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePoint p lst = map removePoint' lst
  where removePoint' shp = filter (/= p) shp
```

Then, many people would recognize that if you have `f x = blah blah blah x`, you can replace that with `f = blah blah blah` (a process known as eta-reduction).  Both the main and helper functions can be eta-reduced like so:

```
removePoint :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePoint p = map removePoint'
  where removePoint' = filter (/= p)
```

Now, there's no point in having a `where` clause so:

```
removePoint :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePoint p = map (filter (/= p))
```

This is pretty good, and most people would stop here.  The truly demented would recognize an opportunity to turn this into "point-free" form by writing:

```
removePoint :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePoint = map . filter . (/=)
```

(Technically, this isn't identical to the previous version, but it's okay as long as `p /= q` is always the same as `q /= p`.)  Now, it looks really clever but no one can understand it just by looking at it, so we have to add a comment:

```
-- Remove Point everywhere it appears in [ShipPoints]
removePoint :: Point -> [ShipPoints] -> [ShipPoints]
removePoint = map . filter . (/=)
```

Awesome!